# MySQL Lost Connection on OpenShift gear

Tags: openshift

I keep getting "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet'" on my gear which happens every 2 to 3 hours. My gear is a scaled instance with php and mysql

Answer (score 0):

First I would check to make sure you're not hitting any memory limitations on your app. Check out this FAQ to find out how to check https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1082-how-to-check-for-memory-limit-violations.

If you are hitting memory limit's then I would suggest creating a scalable app which will put your app and database on separate gears.

Comment: Yes I checked this and not hitting in resource limits and the app is already scaled.